# Why does toString() not print this array of ints?

Tags: java

In working on an Euler problem as a new Java programmer, I have encountered something peculiar related to printing an array.

I do not understand why this is happening - the individual values appear to be correct, when printed individually, but the `toString()` is clearly creating a string which is not what I expect.

I would have expected either a compile error, or the array to be put into a concatenated list. Neither of these happened.

Note: I am not interested in "how to print an array?" but rather understanding why the `toString()` does NOT print the array. There are plenty of resources online available to find how to do so.

```
public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        /* Setup a string/int array converion*/
        int i=0;
        String nums = "123456";
        char[] splitNums = nums.toCharArray();
        int[] ints = new int[nums.length()];

        for (char c : splitNums) {
            ints[i++] = Character.digit(c,10);
        }

        //Print using the string/char[]
        System.out.println(nums);
        System.out.println(splitNums);

        //Values are clearly there
        for (int j : ints){
            System.out.println(j);
        }

        //What is toString() doing? 
        System.out.println(ints.toString());

    }

}
```

Output:

```
123456
123456
1
2
3
4
5
6
[I@4b71bbc9
```

Comment: @Makoto I don't actually care _how_ to do it, I am wanting to know _why_ that happens - the other question only explains how and does not even attempt to answer why.

Comment: What else do you want to know apart from my answer below? I can probably answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`toString()` are implicitly called when you are printing an object. Since `ints` is an array (treated as object) and not a primitive.

When your `ints` are placed within a `println` statement, the `toString()` method inherited from Class Object are invoked printing what you saw on your screen.

**So why does it inherit from Class Object?**

This is because every class in Java implicitly extends from Class Object.

---

To print an array with a println statement, you can do this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayName));
```

It will print out the formatted array nicely for you:

**Example:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

---

### About toString()

> The toString() method returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read.

-From the API of toString-

So in general a `toString()` method makes a printed object meaningful and textually understandable of what the object represents. However there are a few exception when printing object such as String objects and char array. The reason which is self-explanatory (String already in String)

Comment: `toString() are implicitly called when you are printing an object.` That is true if that object is neither a `char[]` or a `String`. But that's just a detail.

Comment: @Tom I totally agree with you, I will add a little bit more to my solution, hopefully it helps OP to certain extend.

Comment: Thanks - this is what I was looking for. Coming from non-Java this is a bit strange to me that all objects inherit methods  from a `Class` object.

Answer (score 3):

The output `[I@4b71bbc9` that you see is the output of the method `Object.toString()`. Arrays are objects in Java, but they don't have their own implementation of a `toString()` method - so `java.lang.Object`'s version is called, which prints this kind of output (see [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--)).

To print an array, do this instead:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```